# Increase int value in null column

Tags: sqlite

I made a stupid mistake and created a column like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (mycol INTEGER, ...)
```

As you can see, I forgot to define a default value like "DEFAULT 0".

In my code, I need to raise the value in "mycol" by 1.

I was baffled when I found out that this code didn't have any effect.

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycol=(mycol+1)
```

The column value stays as it is. In my case "EMPTY" (=no value at all).

I would like to avoid re-creating the table if possible.

I would like to ask if there is any easy way to fix this in the SQL statement so that an EMPTY value is seen as 0 so that

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycol=(mycol+1)
```

on a column value of EMPTY would finally produce the new column value of 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use such as below if your column has null value:

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycol= ifnull(mycol,0)+1
```

Comment: Have I told you lately that I love you?